# How to create a new rule in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to SONAR. Planning to create a new rule

```
//ifStatement/statement[not(block)] ->rule
```

this is the test rule I want to create but when i navigate to quality profile as administrator I get this screen shot and there is no new rule link.  Can any one help me in getting started on how to create a new rule. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

Comment: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create an XPath-based rule for the C# language, so here's how to proceed:

1. Log in as Administrator in your SonarQube instance.
2. Go in your quality profile and look for the "XPath" rule.

   - See [this rule on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/140?commit=Search&rule_activation=&searchtext=xpath&sort_by=SORT_BY_RULE_NAME)
3. Click on "Copy" link on this rule.
4. Fill all the required information to create your new XPath-based rule.
5. Once you save it, you'll be redirected to this new rule in your quality profile: just activate it by checking the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Just a small question.  I want to test the above rule in a program is it possible that there is a inbuilt editor in sonar where I can test a given rule instead of creating a project and testing it with SONAR-RUNNER

Comment: On the following page, you can find the SSLR C# Toolkit that will allow you to test the XPath Query (but not the rule): http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Custom+Coding+Rules. Just download the JAR and execute it with: java -jar sslr-csharp-toolkit-2.1.jar

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did that. Got the java window entered the source code and below the xpath query.  But Evaluate XPath button remains disabled just wanted to know how to enable it.